# change text content on mouseover to img alt property

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have some `img` tag with class name `box`, and a `p` tag with class `title`, i need to change on `mouseover` and change text content of `p` tag to `alt` property of `img` that clicked, please help me.

```
<table style="width:100%;padding-top:200px;border-bottom:5px solid black;">
    <tr style="text-align:right;width:100%;font-size:small;text-align:center;">
        <td class="box" style="width:22%;">
            <a href="http://xxxxxx.com">
                <img src="Images/photo_2016-06-21_12-13-45.jpg" alt="link1" class="imgLogo" />
            </a>
        </td> 
        <td  class="box" style="width:22%;">
            <a href="http://xxxxxxxxx.com">
                <img src="Images/photo_2016-06-21_12-13-18.jpg" alt="link2" class="imgLogo" data-tree="oak" onmouseover="reply_click(this);"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="box" style="width:22%">
            <a href="http://xxxxx.com/pwa">
                <img src="Images/photo_2016-06-21_12-14-00.jpg" alt="link3" class="imgLogo" /> 
            </a> 
        </td>
        <td class="box" style="width:22%">
            <a href="http://xxxx.com">
                <img src="Images/photo_2016-06-21_12-13-51.jpg" alt="link4" class="imgLogo" /> 
            </a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my p tag:

```
<p style="text-align: center" id="title-links" class="title-links">content here</p>
```

i want to write it with javascript, i dont want to use jQuery.

Comment: And where is your `script` ?

Comment: i new in jQuery and javascript! please write script

Comment: `function reply_click(elem){ $('#title-links').text(elem.alt); }`

Comment: thank you Rayon, when i moseout last text content stay for p tag! how can clear content when mouse is out of any of them?

Comment: You have not writte any code for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded solution for this question using by javascript.

Add **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** event properties into the img tag. As below:

```
<img src="Images/photo_2016-06-21_12-13-45.jpg" alt="سیستم مدیریت جلسات" class="imgLogo" onmouseover="changeText(this)" onmouseout="changeTextToDefault()"/>
```

After this, add the following js functions linked to above mouse events.

This **changeText()** function going to execute when mouse pointer come over the displayed img tag. After, it changes text content of **p** tag to the value of **alt** property on **img** tag.

```
function changeText(xTag){ document.getElementById("title-links").innerHTML =xTag.getAttribute("alt");}
```

Also, **changeTextToDefault()** function going to execute when mouse pointer leaves over the displayed img tag. And, it changes text content of **p** tag to the default text.

```
function changeTextToDefault(){ document.getElementById("title-links").innerHTML = "سیستم مدیریت جلسات";}
```

[Here is demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxEdx1cGtECRIJ0ivh8t?p=info)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12760113)

Comment: Tanks for your review Mohd Abdul Mujib. I edited my post according your review.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".imgLogo").on("mouseenter", function() {
     $("#title-links").text($(this).attr("alt"));
 });
```

Also, please note that the class names you gave in your are different to the ones your supplied in your code...

This code also doesn't require a `onmouseover` HTML attribute on the `img`

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in you page.

```
function reply_click(e) {
    $('.title').text(e.alt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`

Script

```
function showalt(elem){ $('#title-links').text(elem.alt); }

function showdefault(elem){$('#title-links').text('سیستم مدیریت جلسات');}
```

**[Here is  a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/npd8dkpu/2/)**

On removing mouse default `<p>` tag content will display